# Lock Screen shows weird old dialog box

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, login-screen

My lock screen looks like this.

[image: Lock Screen]

And when I log in, my computer doesn't get lock.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Do you mean your computer _stays_ locked even when entering the correct password?

Comment: I can login but the default login screen of 18.04 is different from this.